# How to set Panel's Size to full size of tableLayout?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, tablelayout

I have an application based on `Winform`.
In the main app page I have Tablelayout with 2 rows and 2 columns(as you can see in picture), within each table cell there is one panel and it's dock's properties is Fill.

[image]

If I Double-Click on any panel that panel will cover all other panels and will increase to full size off the tableLayout.

I'd like to get a few tips..
Thank you..

Comment: You'd have to change the ColumnStyle and RowStyle of the other column and row, setting their Width and Height to 0.

Comment: Nothing Changed.. there is the method when i click double on mouse:          

private void onDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 0F));
            this.tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 0F));
            label1.Text = "Changed..";
        }

Comment: Add() makes no sense, you want to change the existing RowStyles.  So probably something like this.tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles[1].Height = 0;  You'll encourage SO users to post code that helps you by posting repro code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Great! it works... Thanks..